# Compare two strings (urls) for same domain

Tags: php, url, compare

I'm trying to compare two urls using PHP, ensuring that the domain name is the same. It cannot be the sub-domain. It has to literally be the same domain. Example:

`http://www.google.co.uk` would validate as `true` compared to `http://www.google.co.uk/pages.html`.

but

`http://www.google.co.uk would` validate as `false` compared to `http://www.something.co.uk/pages.html`.

Comment: Seems like a normal string comparison task to me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It's not string that I'm comparing but its content to find the same domain name

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [parse_url()](http://us.php.net/parse+url), and compare the "host" index in the array returned from the two calls to `parse_url()`.

Comment: This is a little old, but you can make this a little simpler by using the second parameter to parse_url. `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)` just gives you the string you want.

Comment: beware: it's not a general method for checking same domain urls, it will fail for example on `http://www.google.co.uk` and `http://mail.google.co.uk`

Answer (score 7):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$url1 = parse_url("http://www.google.co.uk");
$url2 = parse_url("http://www.google.co.uk/pages.html");

if ($url1['host'] == $url2['host']){
   //matches
}
```

Answer (score 3):

simple, use `parse_url()`

```
$url1 = parse_url('http://www.google.co.uk');
$url2 = parse_url('http://www.google.co.uk/pages.html');

if($url1['host'] == $url2['host']){
    // same domain
}
```

Comment: lol, no i didn't, actually my first answer was with ``['hostname']`` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for this

```
$url1 = parse_url('http://www.google.com/page1.html');
$domain1 = $url1['host'];

$url2 = parse_url('http://www.google.com/page2.html');
$domain2 = $url2['host'];

if($domain1 == $domain2){
// something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the answer given by Ariel, the code you could use is similar to the following one:

```
<?php

compare_host('http://www.google.co.uk', 'http://www.something.co.uk/pages.html');

function compare_host($url1, $url2)
{
    // PHP prior of 5.3.3 emits a warning if the URL parsing failed.
    $info = @parse_url($url1);
    if (empty($info)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $host1 = $info['host'];
    $info = @parse_url($url2);
    if (empty($info)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return (strtolower($host1) === strtolower($info['host']));
}
```